# Emmet and Sublime Text 3, only partially expanding abbreviations

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I installed Emmet to Sublime Text 3, but only a part of its functionality is present. I'm missing the child-parent functionality to be specific.

For example, it converts li+TAB to "< li > < /li>" but the Parent-Child syntax is not covered, so ul>li produces ul>< li >< /li > not < ul >< li >< /li >< /ul >.

Answer (score 0):

After further research it seems that Emmet did not install properly althoug i followed the instructions and the client messaged me otherwise. Did a manual install as stated on the Emmet page and now everything works fine.